# Listview memory usage

Tags: java, android, listview, memory, android-viewholder

I have a custom list view which has a text view for showing data, I use the view holder pattern to optimize memory usage, but when scrolling the list view continuously, there's a memory allocation rise (in android monitor memory within android studio)

How should I address the problem?

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewContainer viewContainer;
    View rowView = view;

    if(rowView==null){

        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.lv2rowlayout, null, true);

        viewContainer = new ViewContainer();
        //---get a reference to all the views on the xml layout---

        viewContainer.txten = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txten);
        viewContainer.txtfars = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtfars);



        String s ;
        Typeface custom_font;

        viewContainer.txten.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,sd.enSize);
        s="fonts/"+sd.enFont;
        custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),s );
        viewContainer.txten.setTypeface(custom_font);
        viewContainer.txten.setTextColor(sd.enColor);

        viewContainer.txtfars.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,sd.farssize);
        s="fonts/"+sd.farsFont;
        custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),s );
        viewContainer.txtfars.setTypeface(custom_font);
        viewContainer.txtfars.setTextColor(sd.farsColor);

        rowView.setTag(viewContainer);
    }
    else {
        viewContainer = (ViewContainer) rowView.getTag();

    }

    //---customize the content of each row based on position---
    viewContainer. txten.setText(en[position]);
    viewContainer.txtfars.setText(fars[position]);

    return rowView;
}
```

Comment: since your typeface is not dependent on position, why don't you declare a global variable and initialize it in constructor of list view?

Comment: yes it is true way thank u

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not about the `ListView`, it's about the `Typeface.createFromAsset(...)` There is a known issue about that (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9904) which may cause memory leaks on some devices.
You can cache the Typeface creation like this:

```
public class FontCache {

    private static Hashtable<String, Typeface> fontCache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

    public static Typeface get(String name, Context context) {
        Typeface tf = fontCache.get(name);
        if(tf == null) {
            try {
                tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), name);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
            fontCache.put(name, tf);
        }
        return tf;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead if this: `s="fonts/"+sd.enFont;
        custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),s );
        viewContainer.txten.setTypeface(custom_font);`
You set the Typeface with this: `s="fonts/"+sd.enFont; viewContainer.txten.setTypeface(FontCache.get(s, context));`

Answer (score 0):

try to set as shown in below snippet
`custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),s );` in constructor of Adapter.